# Can't connect to internet on Vmware Fusion on guest os

Tags: networking, vmware-fusion

I have Vmware Fusion installed on Mac Osx Mountain Lion and for some reason I can't connect to the internet on my guest os Windows 7 even though my mac has internet access. Internet used to work fine but suddenly it stopped working for no apparent reason. Tried switching network adapter to Nat,Bridged,Host Only but didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: I had this once - turned out to be a 3rd party firewall product was blocking the vmware client.

Comment: @FreudianSlip I'm running into the same issue that you seem to have solved. Any advice?

Comment: Only as above Brian - it turned out to be a 3rd party firewall application on the Mac - I cant recall which one it was now, but when it was turned off, everything sprang into life.